# Cordova/Phonegap Installation: n error occurred while running the android project

Tags: cordova

I've been stuck here for a couple of days on building a phonegap app into android and for some hours on the current problem. I'm Trying to start work on phonegap/cordova. So facing problems in installation. Currently following [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) documentation of cordova. Anyone having idea about this problem

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello"
 at location "c:\Program Files\nodejs\hello"

c:\Program Files\nodejs>cordova platform add android

c:\Program Files\nodejs>cd hello

c:\Program Files\nodejs\hello>cordova platform add android
Checking Android requirements...
Creating android project...
Preparing android project

c:\Program Files\nodejs\hello>cordova local run android
[Error: Cordova does not know local; try help for a list of all the available co
mmands.]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c:\Program Files\nodejs\hello>cordova run android
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Running app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c c:\Program Files\nodejs\h
ello\platforms\android\cordova\run --device
[Error: n error occurred while running the android project.
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What platform are you using to build this on? I know that the CLI on Windows 7 has been [having problems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4914) when there are spaces in the path.

Can you try to recreate the app on a location without any spaces? For example, 
`C:\\workspace\` or something.

Also, FWIW, `local` is a command that only Phonegap knows, not the regular CLI.

Comment: yups its running now. Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed your earlier comment, but yes you can install it wherever you want. What I do is just have a `C://workspace/` directory where I put all of my work. When you did the `npm install -g cordova` to install cordova, the `-g` flag means that cordova was installed "globally", so you can access "cordova" from any folder on your system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to download cord-ova/phone-gap latest version extract it and place it in the in any one of the drive .(or) Even you can add plugin in the eclipse/STS install it.

Then in eclipse press cntl+N to create a project and write phone-gap you will get the option from that choose and when you try to create a project from the radio button choose your which you have downloaded cordova where it is present and try it.....